# C# Use a dll from abstract class in runtime

Tags: c#, dll, abstract

I am facing a problem I don't know how to solve, as I am very new to programming.

Simplifying the problem, I have a GUI in Visual Studio C# with the following elements:

- Main GUI
- Other GUI's (not relevant for this case...)
- `ExternalControl` class
- Object of the `ExternalControl` class

The `ExternalControl` class shows the same functionality for different external devices, but the implementation of the methods differ among devices. Due to that, I decided to create `ExternalControl` as an abstract class. The different devices are controlled from different classes based on the abstract methods (overriding them) of `ExternalControl`. So I have the following

```
public abstract class ExternalControl
{
    protected int PropertyA;
    protected bool PropertyB;
    protected string PropertyC;

    public virtual void Method1() {}
    public virtual void Method2() {}
    public virtual void Method3() {}
}

public class ExternalControl_DeviceA : ExternalControl {...}
public class ExternalControl_DeviceB : ExternalControl {...}
public class ExternalControl_DeviceC : ExternalControl {...}
```

The actual implementation of those classes is not important, what is important is that they all have the same public methods `Method1() Method2()` and `Method3()`, and are compiled in three different dll's.

I have done this already, but I do not know how to call and use the right dll on runtime upon user selection of the right device.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks,
Ajith

Comment: What is the problem with loading/referencing all three assemblies?

Comment: You can use a Factory pattern to instantiate the correct object

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do it, could you provide an example, including the technique of Factory pattern?